# Error when loading laravel login page? Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I haven't touched the webpack since the beginning of my project at all, suddenly I get this error.
I'm trying to load the login page and get this error and nothing loads

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
     at __webpack_require__ (app.js:64)
     at app.js:73038
```

No idea what this is about, this is my webpack.mis.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require('path');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .webpackConfig({
        output: { chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js?id=[chunkhash]' },
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js',
                '@': path.resolve('resources/js'),
            },
        },
    })
    .babelConfig({
        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import'],
    })
    .version();
```

I haven't changed anything in my webpack, and it was working before as in showing me the page, all I did was move the User model from app to app/Models and change all the mentions of `app/User` to `app/Models/User`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webpack Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52220666/webpack-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-call-of-undefined)

Comment: @Saly3301 I already checked that question, and those solutions don't work for me